# Why is NSTextAttachment image not displayed?

Tags: ios, ios10, nsattributedstring

I'm trying to add an image to an attributed string:

```
NSTextAttachment *locationIcon = [[NSTextAttachment alloc] init];
locationIcon.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"location-pin-icon"];
NSAttributedString *iconString = [NSAttributedString attributedStringWithAttachment:locationIcon];
[string appendAttributedString:iconString];
NSAttributedString *locationNameString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"some text" attributes:linkAttributes];
[string appendAttributedString:locationNameString];
```

Then I simply set `myLabel.text = string;` (where `myLabel` is a `TTTAttributedLabel`)

`location-pin-icon` is a valid image (I've checked it in debugging too). However, the location pin icon is not being displayed in the label (the following "some text" is displayed perfectly though, and `linkAttributes` is just a collection of system font with a custom blue color). I've also tried manually setting bounds to the text attachment, or leaving a space before the text, but nothing seems to work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you print `string` does it appears? Also, where is your code where you set the `attributedString`?

Comment: And if you use a `UILabel` (then `myUILabel.attributedText = string;`, does it work? It wasn't available yet (https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel/issues/287) The issue is a long time ago, but still.

Comment: @Larme it does appear inside my string when I `po` it, though it appears as an `<NSTextAttachment: 0x1702a7080>` object instead of a useful description.

Comment: @Larme yep, it was TTTAttributedLabel. I switched from it and the icon started displaying. I'll never trust "drop-in replacement"s again as this is the exact opposite behavior :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was apparently due to implementation of `TTTAttributedLabel`. The library seems broken. When I've switched from it, the attachment started displaying correctly.